# IntelliJ PAM Authentication Failure on CVS Update after updating password

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

When I'm forced to change my Windows AD account password IntelliJ is no longer able to perform any CVS action (e.g. update) on any checked out class files.

Right-click on class file->CVS->Update
Then the Messages console appears with "Error: Authentication failed. Response from server was: PAM authenticate error: Authentication failure"

I manage to workaround this by clearing the .cvspass file referenced under Settings->Version Control->CVS. It doesn't feel like a very elegant solution. I would have expected a prompt of some sort to re-enter my new password.

Is this the only way to getting cvs to work after updating the password?

Comment: I never came across this myself. I always got the password prompt again, but a college working with the same setup encountered this too. solved it by removing the `.cvspass`-file.

Comment: I've not found an answer yet, but I did find a compromise (somewhat). No need to delete the entire .cvspass file. I just open it and remove the line that has the repo that's giving me problems at the time. I suspect they would all give me authentication problems, but since I work on one project for weeks/months, I dont even notice. Sad that this happens though.

Comment: @user706837 - please post this as an answer, this will help others encountering the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did find a compromise (somewhat). No need to delete the entire .cvspass file. I just open it and remove the line that has the repo that's giving me problems at the time.

Comment: To access the `.cvspass` run the following command `%userprofile%\.cvspass`.
P.S. `.cvspass` file can be found under users folder e.g. `C:\Users\user-name\.cvspass`